# Android webview don't show a part of website

Tags: android, webview

I need to load a proper site into webview. 
What I do:

```
webView.setInitialScale(1)
webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
```

for site

```
webView.loadUrl("https://pnpcss.com/vxyfv2ey/?subId1=fonev")
```

custom WebView:

```
private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
        view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
        return true
    }

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        view.loadUrl(url)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    }
}
```

What I have:
Only the bottom part of site is loaded, the upper is not. If I use chrome on this android phone, it is loaded ok. 
Android versions tested: 5.0.1 & 8. 
What I do wrong?

Comment: The part which is not loaded seam to be an iframe

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in that iframe was not loaded. It is solved with settings.domStorageEnabled = true